# How to include Swift support in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, swift, ide

Eclipse is the IDE of my choice so I searched for a solution to write Swift-based apps in Eclipse.
I found the following project: [swiftclipse](http://github.com/alblue/swiftclipse).

It seems very useful but the problem is that I've no idea how to include it in my Eclipse installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That project does not contain any useful code. It is just a feature project with two plugins each of which only contains an Activator. It has also not had any activity since last June.

Comment: Very unfortunate. But ok, then I have to continue to search for a Swift plugin.